# Jest tests on node module ignoring directory

Tags: javascript, node.js, jestjs

Hi there I am trying to use Jest for a TDD process towards creating a node module. My project structure looks like so

1. lib:

   - `__mocks__`

     - `style.scss`
   - `__tests__`
   - `src`

My issue is I am trying to access the `style.scss` file inside the `__mocks__` directory but when I run in debug mode I can see the `__mocks__` is not present in the source.

Just so you get an idea how I am trying to access it

```
/*
 * Get files directory paths if paths are glob if
 * not return original
 * @param {Array} array of file path
 * @return {Array} array of files found */
const globGetFiles = src => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    src = src || [];

    let rtn = [];
    let options = {};

    async.forEachOf(src, (value, key, callback) => {
      if (!value) {
        callback();
      }
      glob(value, options, (error, files) => {
        if (error) {
          return reject(error);
        }

        rtn.concat(files);
        callback();
      });
    }, error => {
      if (error) {
        return reject(error);
      }
      resolve(rtn);
    });
  });
};
```

and the path I am passing is

```
const sassFile = path.join(process.cwd(), './lib/__mocks__/style.scss');
```